# django CSV upload, add column, store to S3

Tags: python, django, csv, amazon-s3, celery

Python beginner here. I am writing a python django application that requires a CSV upload file. After upload, the file should be given an additional column and then it should be stored on amazon S3 environment.

I managed to create a form to upload a csv file directly to amazon s3 with this tutorial: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html

I have different problems:

1. The upload is currently a synchronous task, and it should be an
   asynchronous task, leaving my django web worker free for other
   users. now the web app is blocked during upload.
2. What would be the best set-up?

asynchronous upload to s3 (task 1) > download csv file from s3 inside a worker (task 2) > create new file inside worker task and add column (task 2 continued) > write the modified task to s3 (task 2 continued)

OR just in one single task

asynchronous upload to worker environment > add column > write to s3

I have celery running, can add code to the queue and it executes correctly. I don't now how to get started on passing the upload to the celery queue and don't know how to decide on which approach for uploading the file (directly to s3 and edit it afterwards or keep it local, do changes and upload afterwards to s3).

Also, the tutorial I used, uses Boto3 to connect to AWS, is this a good way?

thanks for getting me started with this!

Comment: I would keep the upload synchronous and use [AWS lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) to add the extra column. Unless you expect to have thousands of concurrent uses, a web server like Apache or NGINX should be able to handle the reqests just fine.

Comment: if i keep it synchronous, doesn't it mean that when a person is uploading, he blocks the django web worker, allowing no other users to navigate through my django app/webpage? currently, my django app is running on heroku and this lambda looks similar. but i will have to look into lambda more in depth. thanks for the tip!

Comment: When the file is being uploaded, it only blocks the thread that is serving that particular request. This means that if you start uWSGI, for example, with `uwsgi --processes 4 --threads 20 ...`, you will be able to server 80 requests concurrently. You could also try [uWSGI with gevent loop engine](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Gevent.html?highlight=gevent) for even more concurrency: `uwsgi  --gevent 2000`. You have to try out different options for your particular application to see which one works best. Haven't used heroku so not sure how much of this it does for you automatically.

Comment: i am using the gunicorn instead of the uWSGI and seems to have the option to have multiple threads (no processes as far as i can find now). Heroku can run multiple workers on one dyno (=server). Depending on the dyno type, you get multiple cores and more RAM, resulting in more workers and threads it can handle. nevertheless, if I have an upload or a task taking longer then the timeout time, I still need celery as far as I understood - or am I overlooking something?